# Building gumbo-parser dll using mingw in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, dll, gumbo

I want to build Gumbo-parser dll using MingGW. Can you give me some directions on how to do that? It seems that it can be done since it is pure C, with no dependencies. I want to do this despite the presence of VS solution in the source code because I have come across many problems building it in VS2012 Ultimate.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following to compile Gumbo with MinGW successfully:

- Use MinGW installer and install the Basic Setup packages: mingw-developer-toolkit, mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc-g++, msys-base
- Run msys.bat and navigate to the gumbo source code directory (e.g. /c/temp/gumbo-parser.
- Run ./autogen.sh
- Run ./configure
- Run make
- Gumbo libraries are created under the ./libs directory.